# Authentication required error sending email using postfix on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, gmail, ubuntu-18.04

I am new to this and have succeeded in setting up postfix which forward emails to my gmail account. Below is my `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no



# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_un$
myhostname = vend
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = vend, vend.com.ng, vend, localhost.localdomain, localhost

relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

my first few messages went through before it stopped delivering

below is my `/etc/postfix/virtual` file

```
info@yourdomain.com myemail@gmail.com
sales@yourdomain.com my2mail@gmail.com
```

Appreciate help to resolve this

Comment: Error messages from your log files would be helpful

Comment: There are no error messages, just my email showing "Message not delivered" with this "See the technical details below.
LEARN MORE
The response from the remote server was:
530 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError "